# Cheerio extract a link without a closing tag

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I am making a crawler in cheerio and nodejs and I am trying to extract a  without a closing tag. It looks like this:

```
<item>
   <link>http://www.example.com
   <description>...</description>
</item>
```

how would I extract that link? trying to extract the text of the link tag doesn't return anything

Answer (score 0):

You need to have some parser which will parse the input dirty HTML and sanitize it. You can feed DOMPurify with string full of dirty HTML and it will return a string with clean HTML

[Example of clean HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ujgr.png)

Closing dd tag is not present which is added as shown
These clean HTML can now be used to load in cheerio 
[More on DOMPurify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dompurify)

Comment: Hi Pranay. Please do not link out to an example answer. It would be much more helpful to include that HTML in your answer.